# In Angular how can I access my compiled template from a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-scope

I have a directive like so

```
return {
  scope:{
    divid: '@'
  },
  template: '<div id="{{divid}}"></div>'
}
```

and instance like so

```
<direct divid="some-id"></direct>
```

I want to run some javascript after I know that the template has been compiled and id is set to 'some-id'. I tried a controller, pre and post link functions but if I set a breakpoint inside of these I can see that id still equals '{{divid}}' in all cases. Is there anyway to do this? I know I can access the template elements through the compile and link functions but if I could I would like to avoid this as it makes my code a lot more concise and readable.

Comment: Wrap that code in a $timeout to make sure it runs after template is rendered (current digest cycle). And if it does not perform any scope update you can use the 3rd argument of the timeout to turn of forceApply (by setting false).

Comment: Why don't you just access the attribute on the scope via  `scope.divid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap that piece of code inside `$timeout` in a link function, it will make sure that your element is completely rendered since the $timeout is run only after the current digest cycle is completed (provided you already had set the id before the current digest cycle). *And remember to use the third argument (set to false) to turn of digest cycle run if you are not performing any scope updates inside the timeout.*

You can also use a onetime watch if you are not sure when the id is set especially when it is set asynchronously (i.e `divid="{{someId}}"` and `someId` is populated asynchronously).

Then there is a non standard, private property of a scope called `$$postDigest` as well, since it is internal property implementation can change during any future version, so use this at your own risk.

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('direct', function($timeout) {
  return {
    scope: {
      divid: '@'
    },
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<div id="{{divid}}"></div>',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      console.log('Before digest-->', element.find('div').attr('id'));
      //using timeout
      $timeout(function() {
        console.log('In timeout-->', element.find('div').attr('id'));
      }, false);
      //Using non standard postdigest
      scope.$$postDigest(function() {
        console.log('In postdigest-->', element.find('div').attr('id'));
      });

      //Setting up a onetime watch
      var unWatch = scope.$watch(function() {
        return element.find('div').attr('id');
      }, function(val) {
        if (val) {
          unWatch();
          console.log('One time watch-->', element.find('div').attr('id'), val);
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <direct divid="someid"></direct>
  Nothing much here, See the console
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know $timeout waited until the digest cycle completed, thanks!

Comment: yeah they are pushed to async queue, even if you dont specify any duration no timeout will run immediately, there is always a minimal duration required to allocate resources to run the timeout expression. In this case digest cycle has already queued up and timeout pushed to the queue can only run after they are done.